# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\log\phi}\frac{u^2(e^{2u}+1)}{e^{2u}-1}du$, when $\phi$ is the golden ratio

Tags: definite-integrals, golden-ratio

When I do $$e^u=x+\sqrt{x^2+1}$$ in (17) page **9**, see [here](https://www.carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/arcsins.pdf), after some computations then I obtain 
$$\frac{\zeta(3)}{10}=\int_{0}^{\log(\phi)}\frac{u^2(e^{2u}+1)}{e^{2u}-1}du,$$
where $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the **golden ratio** and $\zeta(3)$ is the **Apéry's constant**.

I don't know if this exercise is in the literature:

> **Question.** Can you prove what I say? This is, can you show $$\frac{\zeta(3)}{10}=\int_{0}^{\log(\phi)}\frac{u^2(e^{2u}+1)}{e^{2u}-1}du?$$ Then I can check if my computations were rights. **Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Try with those writings:

$$e^{2u} + 1 = e^u(e^u + e^{-u}) ~~~~~~~~~~~ e^{2u}-1 = e^u(e^u - e^{-u})$$

Thence the integral becomes

$$\int u^2\frac{e^u + e^{-u}}{e^u - e^{-u}}\ \text{d}u = \int u^2\text{cotanh}(u)\ \text{d}u$$

**Another possibility**

Collect a $e^{2u}$ up and down the fraction, to get:

$$\int_0^{\ln\phi}\ u^2\frac{1 + e^{-2u}}{1 - e^{-2u}}\ \text{d}u = u^2\cdot (1 + e^{-2u})\cdot \frac{1}{1 - e^{-2u}}\ \text{d}u$$

In which I write the fraction in that way to make you think about the geometric series. Indeed $e^{-2u} < 1$ in your range, so we can express the last fraction as the geometric series, gaining

$$\int_0^{\ln\phi}\ u^2 \cdot (1 + e^{-2u})\cdot \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} (-e^{-2u})^k\ \text{d}u$$

Arrangino a bit and you'll get:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} (-1)^k \left(\int_0^{\ln\phi}u^ke^{-2uk}\text{d}u + \int_0^{\ln\phi} u^ke^{-2u(1+k)}\ \text{d}u\right)$$

You should be able to continue; you will get some incomplete Gamma Function integrals!

Comment: Very thanks much @KimPeek for your answer. I will wait for more answers, but I will try your calculations

Comment: I'm going to add a new possibility in a while! That should be easier!

Comment: Very thanks much @KimPeek

Comment: Shouldn't those integrals be over $u^2$?

Comment: I understand that you ask to Peek, isn't? Thanks @RonGordon

Comment: i think at this stage this is not really a full answer because the steps which are ''left as excersise'' seem to be non-trivial

Comment: @tired once I tried to solve completely a question, and I got scolded because I wrote the complete answer and "this is not a site in which we do other people's homework" :(

Comment: this doesn't look like homework! go ahead, i would be give away a (+1) with pleasure :)

Comment: @tired One could integrate by parts $k$ times to solve the first (and the second) integrals by finite series. I tried and it involves HyperGeometrical functions, and at this point I think there could be a faster way.. But who knows. I keep going! Thanks, anyway.

Comment: This is exactly the point where things get messy. i would try to find an representation in trilogarithms and use their special values if i where u ;)